`targets::tar_prune()` looks for a target in NA bucket
In a targets project with AWS cloud storage, running tar_prune() returns an error because one of the target to delete apparently misses a proper bucket name:
Deleting 11 objects from AWS S3 bucket project_name /
Deleting 1 objects from AWS S3 bucket NA -
Error:
! Error running targets::tar_prune()

How can I fix this? I am guessing I need to first find the problematic target then fix its metadata but I am unsure how to do any of this.
Why it matters? Running tar_meta(fields = warnings, complete_only = TRUE) returns problems with no longer existing targets. tar_prune() should have removed the metadata associated with those.
I am sorry I cannot provide a reproducible example as I have no idea how to make this error appear again.

I will look first in _targets/meta/meta file and see what could be wrong here, knowing more what is wrong will help picking a solution.

I think I have solved the problem by editing the local file: _targets/meta/meta. I first looked into the file to find where the error was:
# read meta file
meta <- read_delim("_targets/meta/meta", delim="|")
# find where the problem is
filter(meta, name %in% tar_prune_list())

Returns:
# A tibble: 13 × 18
   name      type  data  command depend    seed path  time  size    bytes format repository iteration parent children seconds
   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
4 genres_al… stem  "222… dae157… 3f860…  1.54e9 "buc… t198… ""    5.08e2 rds    aws        vector    ""     ""         0.369
5 genres_mu… stem  ""    71092c… 5784c… -1.61e9 ""    t199… ""    0      rds    aws        vector    ""     ""         0.012
                                                ^
                                                empty value

I then made a copy of the meta file for safety and edited it. I copied the path value of line 4 to line 5, and replaced the name of the target. It has the following format:
bucket=MYBUCKET*region=NULL*key=MYPROJECT/objects/TARGETNAME*endpoint=HASH*version=

I ran tar_prune() again with no error, and tar_meta() now returns the expected results.
Thanks to @defuneste for the suggestion to look into meta.

Good job and thanks for documenting it! only pain point is that we still do not know how this empty value appears ..

this is a big project, and my first big one with targets, I experimented many things, including aws vs. local targets vs. local targets with format=file, plus I'm working on a server that resets every week. It's why I'm writing the doc, this might appear again and I found no doc on targets' github
